# How to display all circles when none is selected in d3?

Tags: d3.js

The title says pretty much all:

I'd like every circles to be displayed before the user decides to select one from the legend.

In the snippet below (you can run it), you can see that i've managed to make the selection part working **only** when the circles are not displayed (at first). I don't know how to reverse that without having the code all messed-up.

Further details: i thought a way to solve this would be to implement a counter to count every `true` `false` sent by `var active = d.active ? false : true;` and then display all the circles once the counts are equals.

```
var truecount = 0;
var falsecount = 0; 

if (active) {truecount+=1} else {falsecount+=1}; 

if (truecount > 0 && truecount == falsecount) {d3.selectAll(".cercle")
                                                 .attr("display", "true)};
```

But:

1/ it doesn't work (i can hear you laughing at how primitive that code is)

2/ I feel there's a much simpler way to achieve this.

Anyone ?

```js
var data = "123456789".split("").map(function(d) {
  return {
    value: d
  }
});



var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .range(["#00baff", "#0014fe", "#00dbaf", "#f4bf02", "#ffa600", "#ff0000", "#ff00c4", "#ee693e", "#99958f"]);

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 600)
  .attr("height", 600)
  
var fullgraph = svg.selectAll("circles")
                   .data(data)
                   .enter()
                   .append("circle")
                   .attr("class", "cercle")
                   .attr("cx", function(d,i) {return 200 + i * 30})
                   .attr("cy", 100)
                   .attr("r", function(e,j) {return 5 + j * 2})
                   .attr("id", function(d,i) {return "cir" + i})
                   .attr("fill", function(d,i) {return color(i)})
                   .attr("display", "none")
                   


var legende = svg.selectAll("bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return 12 + i * 20
  })

legende.append("text")
  .text(function(d, i) {
    return d.value
  })
  .attr("class", "legtext")
  .style("font-family", "helvetica")
  .style("fill-opacity", 0.8)
  .attr("x", 4)
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return 12 + i * 20
  })
  .style("font-size", 10)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color(i)
  })
  .style("text-decoration", "none")
  .style("opacity", 1);

legende.append("rect")
  .attr("class", "recta")
  .attr("x", 2)
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return 1 + i * 20
  })
  .attr("width", 65)
  .attr("height", 15)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color(i)
  });

legende.on("click", function(d, i) {
  var active = d.active ? false : true;
  
  d3.selectAll((".cercle") - ("#cir" + i))
    .attr("display", function() {if (active) {return "none"} else {return "none"} });
    
  d3.select("#cir" + i)
    .attr("display", function() {if (active) {return "true"} else {return "none"} });

 
  d3.select(this)
    .select("rect")
    .style("opacity", function() {
      if (active) return 1;
    })

  d3.select(this)
    .select("text")
    .style("fill", function(e, j) {
      if (active) {
        return "white";
      } else {
        return color(i)
      }
    })
    .raise()
    
  
  d.active = active
});
```

```css
.legende {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.recta {
  opacity: 0.1;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try commenting the line ` .attr("display", "none")
                   `

Comment: If I do so and change ˋnone` by `true`, then the selection won't work.

Comment: It will work but from second selection because on first its needs to be displayed by condition change hat it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D3 means *data driven documents*. So, use the data: bind `active` to the circles and set their display according to it:

```
d3.selectAll(".cercle").attr("display", function(d) {
    if (d.active) {
        return "true"
    } else {
        return "none"
    }
});
```

Here is your updated code:

```js
var data = "123456789".split("").map(function(d) {
  return {
    value: d
  }
});

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .range(["#00baff", "#0014fe", "#00dbaf", "#f4bf02", "#ffa600", "#ff0000", "#ff00c4", "#ee693e", "#99958f"]);

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 600)
  .attr("height", 600)

var fullgraph = svg.selectAll("circles")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("class", "cercle")
  .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
    return 200 + i * 30
  })
  .attr("cy", 100)
  .attr("r", function(e, j) {
    return 5 + j * 2
  })
  .attr("id", function(d, i) {
    return "cir" + i
  })
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color(i)
  });

var legende = svg.selectAll("bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return 12 + i * 20
  })

legende.append("text")
  .text(function(d, i) {
    return d.value
  })
  .attr("class", "legtext")
  .style("font-family", "helvetica")
  .style("fill-opacity", 0.8)
  .attr("x", 4)
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return 12 + i * 20
  })
  .style("font-size", 10)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color(i)
  })
  .style("text-decoration", "none")
  .style("opacity", 1);

legende.append("rect")
  .attr("class", "recta")
  .attr("x", 2)
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return 1 + i * 20
  })
  .attr("width", 65)
  .attr("height", 15)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color(i)
  });

legende.on("click", function(d, i) {
  var active = d.active ? false : true;
  
  d3.select("#cir" + i).each(function(d){
  d.active = active
  });

  d3.selectAll(".cercle").attr("display", function(d) {
      if (d.active) {
        return "true"
      } else {
        return "none"
      }
    });

  d3.select(this)
    .select("rect")
    .style("opacity", function() {
      if (active) return 1;
    })

  d3.select(this)
    .select("text")
    .style("fill", function(e, j) {
      if (active) {
        return "white";
      } else {
        return color(i)
      }
    })
    .raise()


  d.active = active
});
```

```css
.legende {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.recta {
  opacity: 0.1;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you again @GerardoFurtado, your answer makes perfect sense. However I must apologize because my question wasn't perfectly clear: i'm looking for a way to display the circles before **and** after the interaction (hence the idea about a `true` `false` counter). I spent the whole afternoon trying to solve this one by myself, read pretty much all the post regarding toggle functions on SO (including your past answers) and even though I grasp the logic I still can't figure out how to get all the circles back once all the buttons are un-clicked.

Comment: What you want makes no sense for the user because the rectangles are not selected. Anyway, here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/f36u466b/

Comment: "...how to get all the circles back once all the buttons are un-clicked" --> I think it makes sense. Anyway, thank you for your time, your previous answer is the closest to what I'd like to achieve. I will probably rephrase my question later.

Comment: Yes, indeed, it's still not clear to me. Please use the data-binding method of my snippet and post another question, better explaining the behaviour you want. I hope someone else helps you.

Comment: Will do, sir. It was very helpful indeed, thank you.